# How can I get a multiple break on datetime for different plots?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to know if is possible to write a function (ggplot2 packet) that change 'scale_x_datetime(breaks = "x hour")' for each group 'key-val' depending on the column 'time'. The 'time' column is composed of  multiple date/time as shown in the table below. For groups having a bigger interval as key_val=1 (2022-12-01 12:52:30 - 2022-12-04 12:52:30  ) I would like to use breaks of 10 hours and for group having a lower interval as key_val=2 of 1 hour (2022-12-01 12:52:30 - 2022-12-01 15:52:30 ) breaks of 1 hour.

| time | trend_id | num_tweets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 12:52:30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-12-02 12:52:30 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-12-03 12:52:30 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-12-04 12:52:30 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-12-01 12:52:30 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-12-01 13:52:30 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-12-01 14:52:30 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-12-01 15:52:30 | 2 | 0 |

The aim is to obtain multiple plots with different 'breaks' where x = time, y= num_tweet.

This is my code until now:

```
df_split <- split(df4, df4$trend_id) 

for (i in names(df_split)) { 
print(
ggplot(df_split[[i]], aes(x = time, y = num_tweets)) + 
geom_line(color= "red",linewidth=0.3, alpha=0.5) + 
labs(title = paste(" Trend =", i), x = "Data", y ="Number of Tweets") + 
scale_x_datetime(breaks = "10 hour") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 55, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. Just needed a way to indicate how to control your breaks.

```
library(tidyverse)

                 time trend_id num_tweets
2022-12-01 12:52:30        1          0
2022-12-02 12:52:30        1          1
2022-12-03 12:52:30        1          2
2022-12-04 12:52:30        1          3
2022-12-01 12:52:30        2          0
2022-12-01 13:52:30        2          1
2022-12-01 14:52:30        2          2
2022-12-01 15:52:30        2          0

# Recreate your dataframe by copying the above to the clipboard and
# reading that in.
df <- read.delim("clipboard", header=T)

df_split <- split(df, df$trend_id)

ggf1 <- function(gx) {
    df1 = df_split[[gx]]
    # This holds the indicator the trend_id
    tbreak = ifelse(df1$trend_id[[1]] == 1, "10 hour", "1 hour")
    g1 = ggplot(df1, aes(x=time, y=num_tweets))
    g1 = g1 + geom_line(color = "red", linewidth=0.3, alpha=0.5)
    g1 = g1 + labs(title = paste(" Trend =", gx), x = "Data", y = "Number of Tweets")
    g1 = g1 + scale_x_datetime(breaks = tbreak) 
    g1 = g1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 55, vjust = 1, hjust =1))
    g1
}

lapply(names(df_split), ggf1)
```

That produces these two plots.

[image: plot for 10 hour breaks]

[image: plot for 1 hour breaks]

I would change the x axis label to "Time" instead of "Data".